# Nginx: I want to http2_push all js and css files in a directory how can I do?

Tags: javascript, css, nginx, push, http2

files are created and deleted dynamicaly and names change over time due to css and js CMS plugin minifycation process, how can I do all js and css on a directory be pushed by Nginx?

I try do

```
index index.php;

http2_push 'path/to/files'   *min.css; #not working
http2_push 'path/to/files'    *min.js;  #not working
http2_push 'path/to/file' favicon.ico; #works fine
```

forgive me language Im not english native

thanks for your time

Update: After looking for boredom a solution, I decided to go the long way, I modified the base plugin to create a custom one that creates files with defined name every time instead of one with a dynamic name, I have removed all text strings which denote information by removing $ ctime and $ hash from the generation of the static file.

```
index index.php;

http2_push 'path/to/files' static-name.min.css; #working
http2_push 'path/to/files' static-name.min.js;  #working
```

http2_push 'path/to/file/' *.min.js; # still dont works but it does not matter anymore thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Get PHP to do it for you.

First of all set up the following config in Nginx:

```
http2_push_preload on
```

Then get PHP to send preload link HTTP headers in the response to index.php:

```
header('Link: </styles/file.css>;rel=preload;as=style>');
```

Nginx will then use the preload HTTP headers as instructions to send HTTP/2 push requests.

This assumes your PHP code either knows the files you want to push or can find out.

Using preload hints also means that HTTP/1.1 requests will also get preload hints which will tell the browser to request these ASAP even before parsing the returned HTML.

The main downsides with this options are that you 1) can’t do this for static resources (e.g. if using index.html instead of index.php) and also 2) that it won’t start pushing until the index.php response is ready. For the latter [HTTP Status 103 Early Hints](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8297) allows a quick response but can’t find anything to suggest that Nginx supports this relatively new HTTP Header yet.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, your answer is very successful to use http2 push in nginx, but it does not solve the problem, the files min.js and min.css (The name changes every time the minification process starts)

Example
Initial:
footer-62480877-1550389920.min.js
New page or post purge minify file and create new:
footer-78651984-1328469710.min.js

the goal is to push the file 'name'.min.js regardless of the name I have or the number of times the name changes

http2 is working for me rigth now

any ideas?

Comment: Ok but surely your index.php file needs to know the unique names (to reference them in the HTML)? That’s why I was suggesting getting it to initiate the push rather than Nginx. This has the added advantage of not pushing any old files if you forget to clean them up.

Comment: "Ok but surely your index.php file needs to know the unique names" sure, that's the problem, the names are unique but not static, think that the same problem would be solved pushing all files in a specific directory, instead of indicating manually the name of each file, I try to use a wildcard like * min.js but it does not work

Comment: How are the CSS files used in the browser if not referenced by the index.php HTML output?

Comment: like a script "js" and style "css"

Comment: Will the full unique file name? So PHP knows the exact filenames? If so it is able to push the exact filenames.

Comment: thanks, the problem was solved by modifying the plugin to generate a static file name instead of a dynamic one

Comment: Seems like a workaround than a solution to me. If styles.432432.css is generated than that must be what is put in the HTML, which means PHP knows the unique filename, which means PHP could have signaled the push of the unique file name to Nginx using HTTP preload headers.

Comment: a functional workaround ; ) you are right about php and preload